# Given a map $h: S^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}-{0}$ such that $x\cdot h(x)=0$ for all $x\in S^n$, $f:X\to S^n$ is homotopic to $-f$.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

If there is a continuous map $h: S^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}-{0}$ such that $x\cdot h(x)=0$ for all $x\in S^n$ then for any continuous map $f:X\to S^n$, $f$ is homotopic to $-f$.

My work:

Given any such continuous $f:X\to S^n$, I need to find a continuous map $F:X\times I \to S^n$ such that $F(x,0)=f(x), F(x,1)=-f(x)$. I tried to construct such a function using the given assumption $f(x)\cdot h(f(x))=0$ for all $x\in X$.

$$F(x,t)=\frac{|f(x)\cdot h(tf(x))|f(x)+|f(x)\cdot h((1-t)f(x))|(-f(x))}{|| \;|f(x)\cdot h(tf(x))|f(x)+|f(x)\cdot h((1-t)f(x))|f(x)\;||}$$.

This way I get the first two conditions, however, I cannot guarantee that the denominator will always be nonzero. I think I need to construct a similar map, however, all of my attempts so far have been unsuccessful. I would greatly appreciate it if anyone can help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $h$ it is easy to create a map $g:S^n \to S^n$ such that $x$ is orthogonal to $g(x)$ for every $x\in S^n$. Now, it is sufficient to show that the antipodal map $A:S^n \to S^n:x \mapsto -x$ is homotopic to the identity, since then $f \sim A\circ f=-f$.

To show that $A$ is homotopic to the identity, consider the circles $cos(t)x+sin(t)g(x)$ for every $x \in S^n$ and try to use these circles to define your homotopy $A\sim Id_{S^n}$.

Comment: $g(x)=h(x)/||h(x)|$ right? Sorry but I have no idea how to use $cos(t)x+sin(t)g(x)$ to define a homotopy, actually why are these even circles?

Comment: Yes, $g$ is defined like that. For a fixed $x$, look at the plane containing $x$ and $g(x)$ (make sense since they are orthogonal), then $\{cos(t)x+sin(t)g(x) \ \vert \ t\in I\} $ is the unit circle in this plane.  If you want to define a homotopy using these circles, note that $-x=cos(\pi)x+sin(\pi)g(x)$ is in the circle defined by $x$ for every $x$ and that a homotopy from $Id$ to $A$ is a continuous collection of paths from $x$ to $-x$. So what paths could you use ?

Comment: $I$ is defined as $[0,1]$ in the text I'm looking at. So I guess you mean $F(x,t)=cos(\pi t)x+sin(\pi t)g(x)$. However, I still don't understand how each of these points would lie on $S^n$. I mean, how do we show that $||cos(\pi t)x+sin(\pi t)g(x)||=1$ for all $t\in [0,1]$ and $x\in S^n$?

Comment: Of course, you have to take $I=[0,\pi]$ (or $[0,2\pi]$ if you want complete circles). The circle is contained in $S^n$ because $||cos(t)x+sin(t)g(x)||^2=(cos(t)x+sin(t)g(x))\cdot (cos(t)x+sin(t)g(x))=cos^2(t)+sin^2(t)=1$ since $x \cdot g(x)=0$.